# Настроить переключение кнопок

Tags: javascript

Необходимо при переключении между кнопками активировать одну и деактивировать остальные (если они были ранее выбраны).

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

for(var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
   button[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
     this.classList.toggle('active');
   });
};
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  margin: auto;
}

.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">
    <p class="text">Кнопка</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <p class="text">Кнопка</p>
  </div>
    <div class="button">
    <p class="text">Кнопка</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему**, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо, учту на будущее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо просто в обработчике клика перебрать кнопки и удалить у всех класс

```
button.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active'));
```

Также для лучшей читаемости цикл был заменен на `for of`

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

for (var button of buttons) {
   button.addEventListener('click', function () {
     buttons.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active'));
   
     this.classList.toggle('active');
   });
};
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  margin: auto;
}

.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">
    <p class="text">Кнопка</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <p class="text">Кнопка</p>
  </div>
    <div class="button">
    <p class="text">Кнопка</p>
  </div>
</div>
```